# Additional column TempId3 is cretated on migration in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, entity-framework-6

I have

```
public abstract class DocumentBaseModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class SaleCompileDocument : DocumentBaseModel
{
    public ICollection<EmailNotification> EmailNotifications { get; set; }
}



public  class EmailNotification
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int? DocumentId { get; set; }
    public SaleCompileDocument Document { get; set; }
}
```

In `DbContext` I try to set like this :

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<EmailNotification>()
                .HasOne(x => x.Document)
                .WithMany(x=>x.EmailNotifications)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.DocumentId)
                .HasPrincipalKey(z=>z.Id);
```

On create migration I get addition column:

```
            migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
                name: "TempId3",
                schema: "api",
                table: "SaleCompileDocuments",
                type: "integer",
                nullable: false,
                defaultValue: 0);
```

But if I Remove link To saleDoc

```
    public class EmailNotification 
    {
        public int? SaleDocumentId { get; set; }
        //public SaleCompileDocument SaleCompileDocument { get; set; }
    }
        {    
            modelBuilder.Entity<SaleCompileDocument>()
                .HasMany(x => x.EmailNotifications)
                //.WithOne(x=>x.SaleCompileDocument)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey(x=>x.SaleDocumentId);
        }
```

TempId3 is not created

What is TempId3? Why it is created? What for it is created?
With HasPrincipalKey(z=>z.Id) or without, TempId3 is created

Comment: I get the feeling SQL could possibly not be the optimal RDBMS to store _documents_ ... _maybe_. ;) But anyway, it is what it is. Do you _really_ need inheritance here? I always feel that's _a lot_ of hassle with EF / EF Core ...

Comment: In this case document is something like invoice or waybill. Not free document without structure

Comment: I just saw that `Id` in `DocumentBaseModel` is `int` and `DocumentId` is `long`. Shouldn't those match?

Comment: Yes. It is my typing error.